# 301 Redirect two sites to one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two sites that I'm consolidating into one.  The content is different but all of the paths are the same and need to be directed into two new directories on the new site.

Example:

- site1.com/stuff.html
- site2.com/stuff.html

needs to become:

- site1.com/junk
- site1.com/mail

How do I create a 301 redirect in .htaccess that allows me to specify the file since they have the same name and direct it to a new site?

Right now i have something like this, but I don't think it's right

```
RewriteEngine ON
Redirect /stuff.html http://site1.com/junk

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

Redirect 301 /stuff.html http://www.site1.com/mail
```

I hope that makes sense.  Please, let me know if anything needs clarification.  Thanks in advance.

p.s. site2.com's nameserver is pointing to site1.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick with mod_rewrite instead of using mod_alias, which is agnostic to the requested hostnames:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^stuff\.html$ /junk [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^stuff\.html$ http://site1.com/mail [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great!  That makes a lot more sense.  Thanks @Jon Lin.